# how to select sum of values by id's? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So, i have a table with records like this:

```
ID  ORDERS
1    4
1    1
2    4
3    1
3    2
```

I need to create a query that will lead to this situation:

```
ID ORDERS
1   5
2   4
```

I tried with `select id, count(orders) from table group by id having count(orders) > 3` 
but all I get is a strange result in which my ids are strangely numbered.

Comment: `count` just counts the rows with the same ID (as the name implies). You want `sum` (as your question title implies).

Comment: Sharing is caring. Show us what you tried

Answer (score 1):

You need to sum and not count:

```
select id, sum(orders) 
from table 
group by id 
having sum(orders) > 3
```

Comment: So, i tried this solution and I have strange results. It counts, but id get weird. I have an id from 1 to 10 and it makes me numbers 77, 60, 81 ...

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fyeVetGaYxvy7SdcK9uDwC/0 This is how it works for your sample data.

Comment: Oh... i know what i'm doing wrong! I have bad types. Thanks for help! :D

Comment: @electronicspen if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Change your attempt so that you `SUM(orders)` not `COUNT(orders)`

Count doesn't work because it increments a counter by one for any non null value, and doesn't increment for a null value. In the the following table:

```
ID, name
1, John
2, null 
3, Jane
null, null
```

`COUNT(id)` will return 3 - there are 3 non null ID values. `COUNT(name)` will return 2 - there are two non null values. `SUM(ID)` will return 6 - the sum of the numeric values of ID is 6. SUM looks at what the values are, COUNT doesn't. SUM will treat nulls as 0. The special case `COUNT(*)` will count the presence of the row even if all its values are null. `COUNT(*)` will return 4 - there are 4 rows in the results

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports summing up values via `sum` like follows:

```sql
select id, sum(orders) from test group by id;
```

See also [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9bijUXrQXVLzXzEgixSGmf/0).